# Change word 'content' in json response created by CollectionModel

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, hateoas

I want to know if it is possible to change the word 'content' in the JSON response. Links and content are being created by CollectionModel.
JSON example:

```
{
    "links": [],
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pontar",
            "ownerName": "Pontar",
            "country": "Australia",
            "dateCreated": "28-09-2015"
        },
        {
            "id": 193074,
            "name": "Agri",
            "ownerName": "Agri",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "dateCreated": "28-08-2016"
        }
    ]
}
```

Method to create this response:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<FarmListDto>> getAllActiveFarms() {
    List<Farm> farms = farmsService.findActiveFarms();
    List<FarmListDto> dtoList = FarmListMapper.INSTANCE.map(farms);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new CollectionModel<FarmListDto>(dtoList));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the name is most likely defined in a spec to be called "content". changing it could break compatibility with other devices that stick to the standard. Why do you need to change the key name? What's wrong with using "content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResponseEntity does serialize from your java-object, usually, it happens by some library such as `jackson`. There are ready solutions for change property name declarativity. For example:

```
@JsonProperty("contentList")
private List<...>content;
```

If you use `jackson` just use the code above. Else try to find a similar solution with your deserialize library.